# How to repeat a string using if.. I want to let the program if they say yes

Tags: string, if-statement

Please look at the bottom, you can see there my mistake =)

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class BlueJPeriodicalExam {
 static Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Greetings, user!");
    System.out.println("Please type your name:");
    String a = key.nextLine();
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Please choose from the following: things, names, or places");
    String choice= key.next();
    System.out.println("");
    if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("You chose things.");
    if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You chose names.");
    if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("You chose places.");
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Please type any letter from A-Z.");
    String b = key.next();
    System.out.println("");
    if(b.equals("a"))
    {
        if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find an Arrow.");
        if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Albert Einstein.");
        if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit America.");
        System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("A"))
    {
        if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find an Arrow.");
        if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Albert Einstein.");
        if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit America.");
        System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("b"))
    {
        if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Bag.");
        if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Barry Allen.");
        if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Britain.");
        System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("B"))
    {
        if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Bag.");
        if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Barry Allen.");
        if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Britain.");
        System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("c"))
    {
        if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Cabinet.");
        if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Caitlyn Snow.");
        if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Canada.");
        System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("C"))
    {
        if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Cabinet.");
        if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Caitlyn Snow.");
        if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Canada.");
        System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("d"))
    {
        if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Door.");
        if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Dexter Santos.");
        if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Denmark.");
        System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("D"))
    {
        if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Door.");
        if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Dexter Santos.");
        if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Denmark.");
        System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("e"))
    {
        if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find an Eraser.");
        if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Eddie Thawne.");
        if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit England.");
        System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("E"))
    {
        if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find an Eraser.");
        if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Eddie Thawne.");
        if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit England.");
        System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("f"))
    {
        if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Fence.");
        if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Felicity Smoak.");
        if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Finland.");
        System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("F"))
    {
        if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Fence.");
        if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Felicity Smoak.");
        if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Finland.");
        System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("g"))
    {
       if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Grinder.");
       if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Galileo Galilei.");
       if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Greenland.");
       System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("G"))
    {
       if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Grinder.");
       if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Galileo Galilei.");
       if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Greenland.");
       System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("h"))
    {
       if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Hairbrush.");
       if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Harrison Wells.");
       if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Hong Kong.");
       System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("H"))
    {
       if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Hairbrush.");
       if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Harrison Wells.");
       if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Hong Kong.");
       System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("i"))
    {
       if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find an Instrument.");
       if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Isaac Newton.");
       if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Ireland.");
       System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("I"))
    {
       if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find an Instrument.");
       if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Isaac Newton.");
       if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Ireland.");
       System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("j"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Jar.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for James Chadwick.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Japan.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("J"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Jar.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for James Chadwick.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Japan.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("k"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Kite.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Konrad Lorenz.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Korea.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("K"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Kite.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Konrad Lorenz.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Korea.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("l"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Log.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Luise Andrei Pilar.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Libya.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("L"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Log.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Luise Andrei Pilar.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Libya.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("m"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Map.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Michael John D Cunanan.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Manchester.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("M"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Map.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Michael John D Cunanan.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Manchester.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("n"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Notebook.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Nariszah Montecillo.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Norway.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("N"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Notebook.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Nariszah Montecillo.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Norway.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("o"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find an Oven.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Oliver Quinn.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Oman.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("O"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find an Oven.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Oliver Quinn.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Oman.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("p"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Pan.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Philip Phillips.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Philippines.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("P"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Pan.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Philip Phillips.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Philippines.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("q"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Quantum Splicer.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Quilla Ford.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Qatar.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("Q"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Quantum Splicer.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Quilla Ford.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Qatar.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("r"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Rug.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Robbie Amell.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Russia.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("R"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Rug.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Robbie Amell.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Russia.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("s"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Sharpener.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Sona Raymond.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Singapore.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("S"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Sharpener.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Sona Raymond.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Singapore.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("t"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Telephone.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Tony Woodward.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Thailand.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("T"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Telephone.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Tony Woodward.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Thailand.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("u"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find an Umbrella.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Uriel Septum.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Ukraine.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("U"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find an Umbrella.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Uriel Septum.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Ukraine.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("v"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Violin.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Vigay Kumar.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Vietnam.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("V"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Violin.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Vigay Kumar.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Vietnam.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("w"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Wood.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for William Shakespeare.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Washington D.C.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("W"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Wood.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for William Shakespeare.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Washington D.C.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("x"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Xylophone.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Xin Zhao.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Xiao Pei Street.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("X"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Xylophone.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Xin Zhao.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Xiao Pei Street.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("y"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Yoyo.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Yamagato.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Yemen.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("Y"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Yoyo.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Yamagato.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Yemen.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("z"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Zipper.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Zayn Malik.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Zimbabwe.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
    if(b.equals("Z"))
    {
      if(choice.equals("things")) System.out.println("Find a Zipper.");
      if(choice.equals("names"))  System.out.println("You voted for Zayn Malik.");
      if(choice.equals("places")) System.out.println("Please visit Zimbabwe.");
      System.out.println("");
    }
```

I need your help in this part. The **yes** or **no**

I need your help in this part. The **yes** or **no**

I need your help in this part. The **yes** or **no**

I want to repeat the string above with the (Greetings, user)

```
    System.out.println("Would you still like to continue? Type: yes or no");
    String c = key.next();
    System.out.println("");
    if(c.equals("no")) 
    {
        System.out.println("Thanks for cooperating with us " + a + ". You may now exit the program.");
    }
    if(c.equals("yes")) 
    {
                       //// I NEED YOU HELP IN HERE =)
    }
    System.out.println("");
   }
}
```

Thanks for your help! Hope You can help me with this

Comment: Please edit your question to make it readable and understandable.

Comment: Ohhh sure sir   
I'm just having a hard time

Comment: Your code is a prime example of code duplication. You should use loops and methods to bring your code down to a few lines.

Comment: Ohhh. I guess I should study more about this things =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want the program to ask over and over again until you type in "no"?

```
String c = "";
while (!c.equals("no")){
    System.out.println("Would you still like to continue? Type: yes or no");
    String c = key.next();
    System.out.println("");
}
System.out.println("Thanks for cooperating with us " + a + ". You may now exit the program.");
System.out.println("");
```

Btw, use maps and .toLowerCase() on Strings. This will make your code much much shorter:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class BlueJPeriodicalExam {
    static Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Greetings, user!\nPlease type your name:");
        String name = key.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\nPlease choose from the following: things, names, or places");
        String choice= key.next();

        int choiceInt = 0;

        if(choice.equals("things")) choiceInt = 0;
        if(choice.equals("names")) choiceInt = 1;
        if(choice.equals("places")) choiceInt = 2;

        System.out.println("You chose"+choice+".\n");


        Map<string, List<string>> map = new HashMap<string, List<string>>();

        List<string> mylist = ["Find an Arrow.","You voted for Albert Einstein.","Please visit America."],
        map.Add("a", mylist);
        mylist = ["Find a Bag.","You voted for Barry Allen.","Please visit Britain."];
        map.Add("b", mylist);
        mylist = ["Find a Cabinet.","You voted for Caitlyn Snow.","Please visit Canada."];
        map.Add("c", mylist);
        mylist = ["Find a Door.","You voted for Dexter Santos.","Please visit Denmark."];
        map.Add("d", mylist);
        mylist = ["Find an Eraser.","You voted for Eddie Thawne.","Please visit England."];
        map.Add("e", mylist);
        mylist = ["Find a Fence.","You voted for Felicity Smoak.","Please visit Finland."];
        map.Add("f", mylist);

        ...
        ....
        .....


        System.out.println("Please type any letter from A-Z.");
        String b = key.next();

        System.out.println(map[b.toLowerCase()][choiceInt]);
        System.out.println("");


        String c = "";
        while (!c.equals("no")){
            System.out.println("Would you still like to continue? Type: yes or no");
            String c = key.next();
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println("Thanks for cooperating with us, " + name + ". You may now exit the program.");
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you also know how to repeat the question starting from the beginning?

Comment: I edited again the code. I didn't test it, but if you add the rest of the letters to the list, it should work.
To repeat the whole program, you should add that code not to main, but to another function.
Then you add a loop like the one in the end to main, that calls the function as long as a specific string is not entered.